# Airflow not showing the DAGs code when I click on the code tab of a DAG

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-webserver

I have installed Airflow(version 2.7.3) on my machine running ubuntu 22.04 desktop. The installation seems right because everything works. I have changed from the airflow.cfg file only the `sql_alchemy_conn` where I connect with a MySQL Db using the PyMySQL package from python. First I start the scheduler and the webserver using the `airflow scheduler` and `airflow webserver -p 9999`. And then when I try to open the code of one of the example DAGs I get the error below :

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFcmd.png)

Also when I trigger a DAG it is successfully run but the code still isn't displayed. Also logs aren't shown when I click a task but only when I press Read more.

Comment: Can you see the airflow logs in the CLI? Might have some useful info there

Comment: @user430953 thanks for offering your help. The problem seemed that to view code and logs from the UI you have to be logged in as an Admin User. I had created this admin user when I installed airflow as it necessary but I had made a configuration in the `webserver_config.py` file ( this one for reference AUTH_ROLE_PUBLIC = 'Admin' ) that it lands me directly in the home page and not in the login page where I put my admin credentials and therefore nothing was showing in the code tab and logs tab. Don't really know the reason maybe some kind of condition in the airflow code. Thanks anyway !!